# Flask Socket IO ValueError

Tags: python, sockets, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

I am getting the following error on running my code:

***"ValueError: View function did not return a response"***

Following is my Flask Code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, send
from flask import render_template

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['Secret_Key'] = 'mysecret'
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    render_template('index.html')

@socketio.on('message')
def handleMessage(msg):
    print ('Message:' + msg)
    send (msg, broadcast = True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

Following is my index.html code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Chat Room</title>
<script type= "text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.7.4/socket.io.js"> </script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
</head>
<body>
<script type= "text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:5000');

    socket.on('connect',function() {
      send.send('User has connected!');
    });
    socket.on('message', function(msg) {
      $("#messages").append('<li>'+msg+'</li>')
    });

      $('#sendbutton').on('click',function() {
        socket.send($('#myMessage').val());
        $('#myMessage').val('');
    });
});
</script>
<ul id= "messages"> </ul>
<input type="text" id="myMessage">
<button id="sendbutton">Send</button>
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting the following error when I open localhost:5000 through my browser:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

> ```
> @app.route('/')
> def hello_world():
>     render_template('index.html')
> ```

You should return the rendered template, change to:

```
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

The other function likely has the same problem.

Comment: I can't believe, what i just did there :(